minikube: cannot start cluster after deleting docker network
I mistakenly deleted the minikube Docker network and now minikube start fails:
$ minikube start --driver=docker
W0605 11:59:09.634722   13040 main.go:291] Unable to resolve the current Docker CLI context "default": context "default": context not found: open C:\Users\mirighi\.docker\contexts\meta\37a8eec1ce19687d132fe29051dca629d164e2c4958ba141d5f4133a33f0688f\meta.json: The system cannot find the path specified.
  minikube v1.32.0 on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 10.0.19045.3930 Build 19045.3930
✨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Pulling base image ...
  Restarting existing docker container for "minikube" ...
  StartHost failed, but will try again: driver start: start: docker start minikube: exit status 1
stdout:

stderr:
Error response from daemon: network 23fafd166771dfcec96b7cd0ce08798de201612fd5937f44aa0d6be6324403e2 not found
Error: failed to start containers: minikube

  Restarting existing docker container for "minikube" ...
  Failed to start docker container. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: driver start: start: docker start minikube: exit status 1

stderr:
Error response from daemon: network 23fafd166771dfcec96b7cd0ce08798de201612fd5937f44aa0d6be6324403e2 not found
Error: failed to start containers: minikube


❌  Exiting due to GUEST_PROVISION: error provisioning guest: Failed to start host: driver start: start: docker start mistdout:
stderr:
Error response from daemon: network 23fafd166771dfcec96b7cd0ce08798de201612fd5937f44aa0d6be6324403e2 not found
Error: failed to start containers: minikube


╭───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                                           │
│      If the above advice does not help, please let us know:                             │
│      https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose                           │
│                                                                                           │
│    Please run `minikube logs --file=logs.txt` and attach logs.txt to the GitHub issue.    │
│                                                                                           │
╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯


How can I fix this? Is there a solution that doesn't require the deletion and recreation of the minikube cluster?
I mistakenly ran docker network prune, forgetting that I had a minikube container (the command prompts to confirm the choice, but doesn't tell the networks that will be deleted in advance...). I later noticed that it also deleted the network minikube.
I then tried recreating the network with docker network create minikube, but minikube start --driver=docker keeps failing.

try to connect the minikube container to the network 
docker network connect minikube <container_id>
then restart the minikube container
